# how to get/extract public key from created self signed certs using makecert

Tags: windows, security, ssl

I have created self signed certs using "makecert.exe" from visual studio command prompt from my windows 10 machine using the following commands as shown below:

makecert -n "CN=TempCA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer
makecert -sk SignedByCA -iv TempCA.pvk -n "CN=SignedByCA" -ic TempCA.cer SignedByCA.cer -sr currentuser -ss My

And now i wanted to export/extract the public key from the created cert and wanted to verify it i extracted the public key.

Kindly guide me on the same